# Using crontab with dzdo su

Tags: python

I have to use the command `dzdo su` to move to the root user in order to do anything on a VM I have access to. After using the command `dzdo su`, I am able to run a small python script I have written without issue. I have put this script into the crontab of the root user. When the script runs from the crontab of root however it fails because it cannot find the python modules I have installed to use in the script, for example I get something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scripts/utps/utpsui_getData.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pymysql.cursors
ImportError: No module named pymysql.cursors
```

To troubleshoot I changed the script to just the following code:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
exit()
```

When I run the script from the root crontab I get this:

```
['/scripts/utps', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

When I run the script from the root command line I get this:

```
['/scripts/utps', '/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/lib64/python38.zip', '/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/lib64/python3.8', '/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests-2.24.0-py3.8.egg', '/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3-1.25.10-py3.8.egg', '/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chardet-3.0.4-py3.8.egg', '/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi-2020.6.20-py3.8.egg', '/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages', '/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

Why whould the path be different between the two when it's the same user? How can I make sure I have identical environments between the root shell and root crontab (assuming this is my problem)?

Comment: did you try to run in crontab like it? `* * * * * sudo python3 /path/to/file.py`

Comment: I tried variations of these to no avail: `* * * * * sudo python3 /path/to/file.py`,  `* * * * * dzdo python3.8 /path/to/file.py`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After poking around some more I found three different ways of fixing my problem, all three of which came from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148133/how-to-set-crontab-path-variable. Does anyone know which of these is best and why or is there really no functional difference?

```
* * * * * bash -lc "python /scripts/utps/utpsui_getData.py >> /var/log/utpsui_getData_PPM.log 2>&1"


* * * * * . /etc/profile; python /scripts/utps/utpsui_getData.py >> /var/log/utpsui_getData_outputNullRate.log 2>&1


PATH=/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/bin:/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/bin:/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/bin:/usr/share/centrifydc/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/cfengine/bin:/var/cfengine/bin
* * * * * python /scripts/utps/utpsui_getData.py >> /var/log/utpsui_getData_PPM.log 2>&1
```